# Can force change mass in a system?

Tags: special-relativity, forces, mass, mass-energy

My physics teacher defined force as "an agent that may change the shape, state of motion, size, or mass of an object" but I disagreed with him about "mass" being changed in any situation.
When I asked him and told him that the mass of a system cannot be changed by force, he told me it is beyond my understanding and it could be related to Einstein's equation $E = mc^2$.
I still do not understand it.

First: is it correct that force can change mass? An example will help me.

Second: how could this be related to mass-energy?

Comment: I think you mean "beyond" not "upon". Maybe he is confusing speed with acceleration when thinking of relativistic mass, which is a concept modern physicists apparently do not like because it is misleading.

Comment: oh sorry, you got it..
I mean.. maybe.. that could be right

Comment: Or he means density? But that goes hand in hand with size.

Comment: honestly, I don't know

Comment: There is no reason for him to define force in this way.  It is a very confusing and unusual definition.  And i guess he may be confused about special relativity too.

Comment: And the force is not an agent but a physical quantity that is used to describe interactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force can change mass in two senses:

First: force can change the mass of an object by speeding it up or slowing it down as measured by an observer in an inertial frame. An inertial frame is one which does not accelerate.

$E = mc^2 = \gamma m_0 c^2$

where the Lorentz factor $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$

and $m_0$ is the rest mass: the mass measured by an observer who measures the relative velocity ($v$) of the mass to be $0$.

Applying a net force to a massive object changes its velocity by Newton's 2nd law, and since $m = \gamma m_0$ and $\gamma$ is a function of velocity, mass is changed even though rest mass, which is what is usually meant by "the mass of the object" stays the same.

In short: increasing kinetic energy $T$ of a system increases mass $m$ by $\Delta T/c^2$, while leaving rest mass $m_0$ unchanged.

---

Second: force can change the mass of an object at rest with respect to an observer by re-arranging it into a higher or lower energy state, which either sequesters energy (hence mass) in the object or dissipates it (as light, heat, or sound) into the environment.

Consider an ideal spring initially in its equilibrium state. We do work $\Delta U = .5 k x^2$ to the spring, compressing it by a displacement $x$, and we trap the spring mechanically in its compressed state. Here we have increased the energy, and hence the mass of the system in a reference frame in which the system is stationary, by bringing energy in from **outside** the system (applying a force) and **storing** it in the system's rearranged configuration.

For a spring the potential energy of configuration is a vanishingly miniscule fraction of the total mass-energy of the spring.

In short: increasing potential energy of configuration $U$ of a system increases rest mass $m_0$ by $\Delta U/c^2$, while leaving Lorentz factor $\gamma$ unchanged.

Comment: Is the right answer: +1 from me.

Comment: To the OP: The entity $m=\gamma m_0$ is called *relativistic mass*, a concept that is usually frown upon nowadays.

Comment: I dislike the term "relativistic mass" as it implies that the Lorentz transformation goes the wrong way and promotes confusion. Mass is the mass that you measure. At a known acceleration e.g. $g$, it's measurable by a displacement of a calibrated spring. A hot substance weighs more than a cold substance. If you insist that $m:=m_0$ you have to abandon $F_g \propto m$ and radically modify the entire concept of inertia.

Comment: In the first case, it might be better to say that the *forward inertia* of the object changes.  As @md2perpe points out, *relativistic mass* went out of favor a half century ago because it  is confusing, and contradictory.  Imagine the object is moving North near $c$, and a force is applied in the East direction.   You wouldn't put the relativistic mass into $f=ma$.  Einstein explicitly discouraged the use.

Comment: @gs. I didn't say that the concept should be used. But it's good to know about it since one might see it here and there.

Comment: @garyp. You would however put the relativistic mass into $\mathbf{f}=\frac{d}{dt}(m\mathbf{v}).$

Comment: @garyp ultimately this is just a quibble about terminology and I grant that $m:=m_0$ is the common use whether I dislike it or not. However, I feel compelled to point out that while $\vec f=m \vec a$ is false for $m:=m_0 \gamma$, $\vec f= \frac {d}{dt}(m \vec v)$ is true; while, for $m:=m_0$, both equations are false for large $v$.

Comment: Contrary to many people here I'm not rabid about the use of *relativistic mass*. It was used in the literature from which I learned about the theory of special relativity. The important is that one understands how things work and that matter is not produced when an object gains speed.

Answer (score 1):

Force working along a way is work, so W=F*s. so the energy of an object gets higher with its velocity, and then this energy increases the mass.If the mass of a non moving object ist m0 then the mass of the moving object is $m=m_0*\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ in this sense an accelerating force can increase mass. But citing the force as mean of acceleration includes this, an the "increasing mass" is very far fetched.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about classical physics I would say absolutely not. Force should be defined as an agent that changes the **state of motion** of the system.

Moreover, it is even usual to write Newton's 2nd law as
\begin{equation}
F=\frac{dp}{dt}
\end{equation}
where $p$ is the linear momentum. Thus we say that force in an agent that causes a change in the momentum of the system.

Comment: Does that definition account for something like static pressure?

Comment: Well, why wouldn't it?

Comment: But not is Relativistic physics: there you are wrong. See 'g_s' answer.

Comment: If I press my hand against a wall, neither my hand nor the wall is in a state of motion..

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a box filled with a substance of some kind in a vacuum in orbit. In other words, a closed system. We can measure the entire mass of this box by measuring the... mass of the box! But, since E = mc^2, we can also measure the entire internal energy of the box by measuring the mass of the box. From outside the box, all of the matter and energy in the closed system are indistinguishable.

Thus, if we take our box and add 1 BTU of heat to it, we have increased the internal energy by 1 BTU. If we then weigh our box after doing so, we will find that the mass of the box has increased by about 12 picograms. If we add a million BTU's, we can get the mass of the box to increase by about the mass of a fine grain of sand (15.6 μg). If we add 13 trillion BTU's, which is a lot of heat, we would increase the mass of the box by the mass of a baseball (150 g)... and so on.

And we could do this with any kind of force, it doesn't have to be heat specifically. If we wanted to, we could, for example, punch the box over and over again and we would see the same effect. A punch could deliver around 40 joules, and it would take about 35 billion punches to increase the weight of the box by the same fine grain of sand.

There are more quantum explanations that relate to Einstein's equation that describe matter as nothing more than trapped energy, but I am not qualified to go into that kind of detail...